# in flutter BottomNavigationBar not working

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

```
 bottomNavigationBar: new BottomNavigationBar(items: [
    new BottomNavigationBarItem(icon: new Icon(Icons.account_balance))]),
```

When I run, I get this error

[image: Error]

Comment: Add the error message you get in plain text to your question.

Comment: Be more specific, and be sure that you have the exact TabBar items as the Navigation Bar Items

Answer (score 0):

As the error suggested it needs 2 or more items in bottom navigation bar. The idea is, if you have a navigation bar you should have multiple items to navigate. If you want only one item don't use `BottomNavigationBar`

Answer (score 0):

You need to have at least 2 children for your `items` like:

```
bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
  items: [
    BottomNavigationBarItem(
      icon: Icon(Icons.account_balance),
    ),
    BottomNavigationBarItem(
      icon: Icon(Icons.account_circle),
    ),
  ],
)
```